# PHP: Compare float value from MSQL database with variable

Tags: php

I have a table in my database called users with one column called mon of type Float. I want to compare the column with an input from a texbox assigned to a variable.

```
$amt_chk = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT mon FROM users WHERE id = '$user_id'");

       if (isset($_POST['mon']) > ($amt_chk)) {

            $results="<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissible'>
                    <a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a>
                    <strong></strong>Not enough Funds!
                  </div>";
       }
```

Comment: in sql query `"SELECT mon FROM users WHERE id = '$user_id' and mon = '$_POST['mon']'"`..... this is a sample query. i suggest use PDO with bind parameters

Comment: what sort of comparison are you trying to perform, greater than, equal to, less than, not equal to and you haven't stated your problem

Comment: can you elaborate more on this ? What exactly problem you want to solve?

Comment: Sorry if i wasn't clear earlier. It's should work like a payment system. The code i posted is supposed to check the database for how much money (mon) is left in it and warn the user when he/she tries to send more than he/she has.

Answer (score 1):

I would try floating both values to make sure you are comparing 2 floats:

```
if (isset($_POST['mon'])) :
    $amt_chk = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT mon FROM users WHERE id = '$user_id'");
    $mon = (float) $_POST['mon'];
    $amt_float = (float) $amt_chk;
    if ($mon > $amt_float) :
        // do your thing
    endif;
endif;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to compare float with character data, you can use `CAST` or `CONCAT`. It is not advisable to typecast your MySQL result, and you must think about the types of data you are using and storing. A better approach would be to typecast the input data (in `$user_id`), as it doesn't mingle with the database data.

However, you may use `cast()` as bellow:

```
 SELECT CAST(mon AS CHAR) FROM users WHERE id = `$user_id`
```

The `cast` function typecasts the result into type you supply. From the MySQL documentation:

> Cast functions and operators enable conversion of values from one data type to another.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html

You can also use `CONCAT` as it expects string arguments, and implicitly converts float to char.

```
SELECT CONCAT(mon) FROM users WHERE id = `$user_id`
```

More at the official documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html